# How can I make python continuously check for an item in a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, text

I have the following code:

```
with open('file.txt', encoding="utf8") as inputFile:
    data = inputFile.readlines()
    inputFile.close()

for i, line in enumerate(data):
    if any([x in line for x in ['nl']]):
        with open("nl.txt", "w+") as nl:
            nl.write(line)
    if any([x in line for x in ['be']]):
        with open("be.txt", "w+") as be:
            be.write(line)
    if any([x in line for x in ['pl']]):
        with open("pl.txt", "w+") as pl:
            pl.write(line)
    if any([x in line for x in ['de']]):
        with open("de.txt", "w+") as de:
            de.write(line)
```

This code searches for keywords in a text file and if it writes the entire line to a text file. But for some reason it stops after getting one result. How can I make it loop until all the lines in the file have been checked?

Comment: Please provide example input file and the output of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You open the file in the mode `w+` overwriting any previous content, causing the illusion that it only finds one result. Change your lines with `open` like so to use the mode `a+`:

```
with open('file.txt', encoding="utf8") as inputFile:
    data = inputFile.readlines()
    inputFile.close()

for i, line in enumerate(data):
    if any([x in line for x in ['nl']]):
        with open("nl.txt", "a+") as nl:
            nl.write(line)
    if any([x in line for x in ['be']]):
        with open("be.txt", "a+") as be:
            be.write(line)
    if any([x in line for x in ['pl']]):
        with open("pl.txt", "a+") as pl:
            pl.write(line)
    if any([x in line for x in ['de']]):
        with open("de.txt", "a+") as de:
            de.write(line)
```

Or you can even keep the files open while the loop runs, something like:

```
with open("nl.txt", "w+") as nl:
    for i, line in enumerate(data):
        # Other code here
```